# Change bullet icon to double quote

Tags: html, css, html-lists, pseudo-element

I have a List in HTML. 
Now I would like to change the bullet icon to a double quote icon.

I have found that interesting [website](http://www.artishock.net/coding/css-list-styling-using-ascii-special-characters/).

So I have the code as below:

```css
.listStyle li:before {
  list-style: none;
  content: "\00BB";
}
```

```html
<ul class="listStyle">
  <li>SOME TEXT</li>
  <li>SOME TEXT</li>
  <li>SOME TEXT</li>
  <li>SOME TEXT</li>
  <li>SOME TEXT</li>
  <li>SOME TEXT</li>
  <li>SOME TEXT</li>
</ul>
```

The Screenshot looks like that:

[image: HTML list with bullets and double quotes]

Instead of the bullet icon I need the double quote icon. 
Not both next to each other.

How can I achieve this?

What I need to avoid is that the line is in the same vertical line when a line break is needed: [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are applying the `list-style` property on the pseudo elements rather than on the `li` elements. For the double quote alignment, you can use absolute positioning with :

```css
.listStyle {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left:1.5em;
}
.listStyle li{
  position:relative;
}
.listStyle li:before {
  content: "\00BB";
  position:absolute;
  right:100%;
  width:1.5em;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="listStyle">
  <li>SOME TEXT<br/>second line</li>
  <li>SOME TEXT</li>
  <li>SOME TEXT</li>
  <li>SOME TEXT</li>
  <li>SOME TEXT</li>
  <li>SOME TEXT</li>
  <li>SOME TEXT</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem that I still have is that the text is aligned with the list icons. But the list icons have to be next to the text on the left when a line break is needed. I will update my post to show what I need to avoid

Comment: Adding padding to the `<li>` and a negative margin to the pseudo element should work

Comment: @jublikon I updated the answer with a solution for the double quote alignement

Comment: @web-tiki Your answer works great. Thank you. I have one little question left: How can I achieve a space between the text and the icon ? Adding a space before the text is ignored by the browser

Comment: @jublikon I added some space to the left with padding on the `ul` element and centered the double quotes with a width on the pseudo element and `text-align:center;`

Comment: Works fine for me ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can change the bullet by doing the following:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left:0px;
}
ul li:before {
  content: "\00BB";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

The `padding-left:0px;` will remove the padding to the left so it doesn't have an indent anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This will prevent new lines from wrapping underneath the bullet:

```
.listStyle li {
    list-style: none;
}
.listStyle li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  margin-left: -1em;
  content: "\00BB";
}
```